# Run cucumber test execute from jar with command line --tags @my-tag

Tags: java, jar, cucumber, executable

I have built a cucumber test executable jar using the maven-assembly-plugin option and was successfully run the executable jar that run all the cucumber test within it.

However, I like to try to run the executable with optional tags specified on the command line but could not seem to do so.   Any help and suggestion would be greatly appreciate.

My sample code is in github:

https://github.com/txt8888/cucumber-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `main()` method of the `Main` class from the `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` package.

```
public class DreamCarMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main.main(new String[] { "-g", "org.phan.kata.cucumber.integration.stepdefs", "-p", "pretty", "-t", args[0], "classpath:features" });
    }
}
```

There is no need for the `RunWith` and `CucumberOptions` annotation. Replace the TagExpression with whatever tags u want to execute. If you want to do some action after the call then use the `run()` method instead of the `main()`.

```
java -jar cucumber-integration-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar @TagExpression
```