# Executing cucumber jar from command line

Tags: java, command-line, cucumber

Though the all feature files are reside in resources folder, after executing jar using command line, It says,

> No features found at [classpath:src/main/resources]

Command line I used

```
java -jar cucumber-file.jar
```

Below is the main method. second argument is for step definitions which are located in methods folder. Last argument is for feature files which are located in resources folder.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String[] arguments = {"-g", "com/test/methods", "classpath:src/main/resources"};
    cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);
}
```

I tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195084/run-cucumber-test-execute-from-jar-with-command-line-tags-my-tag) and did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The files in `src/main/resources` are put at the root of the classpath.

That is you should replace `classpath:src/main/resources` with `classpath:`.

Comment: String[] arguments = {"-g", "com/test/methods", "classpath:."}; I replaced this way. Then I got the same error. "No features found at [classpath:.]"

Comment: String[] arguments = {"-g", "com/test/methods", "classpath:"}; This way it worked. But then there happened another issue. It doesn't find step definition. I guess reason may be in the path I have given.  "com/test/methods". Is this path wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I'll update my answer. About the steps classes, where are they (which package)?

Comment: All step definitions are in this path src/main/java/com/test/methods

Comment: Did you try with `com.test.methods` instead?

Comment: Yes. I tried with that. It did not help.